# How can I get the current day in Robot Framework?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Im new to automated Testing.

Now I want to select the current weekday from a list.

I want to us following Keyword:

```
Selenium2Library.Select From List by Value ${day_of_the_week}
```

How can I get the Current day in Robot Framework? Is there a simple solution to my Problem?

The best would be a variable that gives me the current day in german Language.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you selecting the current date from a HTML element or do you just want the current date logged to a variable?

Comment: I can get the current date from a Library. The Problem is i need to get the current day of the week. *For example: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html) `DateTime`

Which can be called by:

```
**** Settings ***
Library    DateTime
```

You can use the `Get Current Date` keyword and assign it to a Var and specify the format. For example:

```
${CurrentDate}    Get Current Date    result_format=%d-%m-%Y
Log    ${CurrentDate}
```

In your case you need to change the `Result_format` to retrieve the current day. This would be

```
${CurrentDay}    Get Current Date    result_format=%A
Log    ${CurrentDay}
```

Which, when viewed in the log, would retrieve "Thursday"

The list of formats can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Hope this helps you!

EDIT:

Due to the `DateTime` Library not supporting local names for the dates (Montag for Monday in German for instance) The Asker switched to the `%w` format to return 0-6 range. Then used an index to change the int into a string of the date!

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i needed. Can you tell me how i can change the local language. Because my System language is German but the output is English.

Comment: I was wrong in saying that it will take your local language. If you want to switch it over to de_DE you will have to do some work in Python... Or - if you don't mind being dirty; you could just read the variable when gets logged. If it equals to "Monday" set it to "Montag". But that would be messy and dirty... There is nothing by default within the DateTime library to do this for you :(

Comment: @FloZ. Actually, it should grab your local area... So I do not know why it's not... Is your language set to DE on the machine which is running the Robot Tests?

Comment: It is worth to mention that `Get Current Date` is available from ver. 2.8.5 (in library `DateTime`).

Comment: @FloZ. have you considered to accept the proposed solution? thanks

Comment: @JanKovařík I used the proposed soulution but  used the ´result_format0%w´which gives me the day in an decimal number from 0-6. Then i used the indx to select the corresponding day from a list!

Comment: @FloZ. Then it is great to mention that :) Thanks